# How to connect CSS file to ASP.NET Core's _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines
@inject IWebHostEnvironment Environment
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MerchShop</title>
    
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
```

This is the `_Layout.cshtml` from ASP.NET Core 6.0 with react + individual accounts and I'm trying to change styles for identity pages, which uses this layout.

All the pages in `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account` and `Pages/Shared/` and `wwwroot/` I created with add new scaffoled item > identity (if you will try to generate them and you will get an error, add this NuGet package `Microsoft.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core` and update all the others).

So technically I didn't write a single line of code except `update-database` in package manager console in the beginning and still `site.css` changes nothing, so I don't know what to do.

BUT if I will remove a link to `bootstrap.css`, bootstrap will disappear from the page, so this link works - BUT if I will go to that file and remove all lines of code in it, it will still work just like before. I don't know what to do please help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

nvm i just had to create `Identity/css` folder in wwwroot...